# Mongo-Connector unable to connect MongoDB Replica set for Elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, docker, elasticsearch

Yesterday I created a Replica set using Docker-compose based on the instructions shown here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlw7vWISaF4

The containers all create, and I've managed to seed the data as well, so using Robo3T I can view my collections.  I did this as I need the mongo-connector to connect MongoDB to Elasticsearch.

This is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo-rs0-1:
    image: "mongo-start"
    build: ./mongo-rs0-1
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-rs0-1/data:/data/db
    depends_on:
      - "mongo-rs0-2"
      - "mongo-rs0-3"

  mongo-rs0-2:
    image: "mongo:3.6.4"
    command: --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-rs0-2/data:/data/db

  mongo-rs0-3:
    image: "mongo:3.6.4"
    command: --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
    ports:
      - "27019:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-rs0-3/data:/data/db

  setup-rs:
    image: "setup-rs"
    build: ./setup
    depends_on:
      - "mongo-rs0-1"

  mongo-db-seeder:
    build:
      context: ./mongo-db-seed
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-db-seed/seeddata:/opt/seeddata
    depends_on:
      - "web-app"
    command: "./import_mongo.sh"

  adminmongo:
    image: "mrvautin/adminmongo"
    ports:
      - "1234:1234"

  #Test Application
  web-app:
    image: docker-node-express-mongoreplicaset-app
    build: ./web-site
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./web-site:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - "setup-rs"
```

This is the replica.js that configures that replica set;

```
rsconf = {
  _id : "rs0",
  members: [
    { _id : 0, host : "mongo-rs0-1:27017" },
    { _id : 1, host : "mongo-rs0-2:27017" },
    { _id : 2, host : "mongo-rs0-3:27017" }
  ]
}

rs.initiate(rsconf);

rs.conf();
```

I installed Elasticsearch and that's running on port 9200 waiting for an index to be built.

This is my host file (etc/hosts) I'm running on os x.

```
##  
# Host Database  
#  
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface  
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.  
##  
127.0.0.1   localhost  
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost  
::1             localhost
```

However when I run this command (the containers, and Elasticsearch are all running)

> mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t localhost:9200 -d elastic2_doc_manager

I get this error:

> ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongo-rs0-3:27017: [Errno 8] nodename nor
>   servname provided, or not known,mongo-rs0-1:27017: [Errno 8] nodename
>   nor servname provided, or not known,mongo-rs0-2:27017: [Errno 8]
>   nodename nor servname provided, or not known

I've had a good search this morning, and I can't find anything that points to the issue.  The replica set appears to be running fine, Elasticsearch is running, but something is missing.

Comment: Can you provide your `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, apologies in the delay posting.  I'm using Mac os x here, so I'll add it to the above question.